# Fill = T won't work with single letters (?) [R]

Tags: r, fill

I'm using 'fill = T' on a file that has single letters separated by commas:

```
    Pred
1   T,T
2   NA
3   D
4   NA
5   NA
6   T
7   P,B
8   NA
9   NA
```

using the command:

```
sift <- read.table("/home/pred.txt", header=F, fill=TRUE, sep=',', stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Which I was hoping the sift will turn out as:

```
    V1 V2
1    T  T
2 <NA>    
3    D    
4 <NA>   
5 <NA>   
6    T   
7    P  B
8 <NA>   
9 <NA>
```

However, it comes out like:

```
    V1 
1    T 
2 <NA>    
3    D    
4 <NA>   
5 <NA>   
6    T   
7    P 
8 <NA>   
9 <NA>
```

This code works when there are multiple sampleIDs (separated by a comma) in each row - but not for single letters.  Does 'fill' work for single letters? Stupid question, I know.

Comment: Can you post the full file somewhere and provide a link?

Comment: I don't think I have anywhere personal I can upload it - is there a recommended place?

Comment: You could use Dropbox.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjb241s16t63ev8/pred.txt

Comment: This file has only one column, and apparently no comma's. The header is "SIFT_PRED"

Comment: Yeah - there is one column, with a couple of entries with a combination of T and D (Or its NA), separated by a comma.  This is not the exact file I used, but more or less the same with a header.

Comment: Now if you replace T and D with something that resembles a sampleID then the above code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a workaround:

```
url  <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bjb241s16t63ev8/pred.txt?dl=1&token_hash=AAEBzfCGgoeHgNTvhMSVoZK6qRGrdwwuDZB3h8lWTZNtkA"
df.1 <- read.table(url,header=F,sep=",",fill=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
dim(df.1)
# [1] 149792      1     <-- 149,792 rows and ** 1 ** column

df.2 <- read.table(url,header=F,sep=",",fill=T,stringsAsFactors=F, 
                   col.names=c("V1","V2"))
dim(df.2)
# [1] 149633      2     <-- 149,633 rows and ** 2 ** columns

head(df.2[which(nchar(df.2$V2)>0),])
#      V1 V2
# 1000  T  T
# 2419  T  T
# 3507  T  T
# 3766  T  D
# 4308  T  D
# 4545  T  D
```

`read.table(...)` creates a data frame with number of columns determined by the first 5 rows. Since the first 5 rows in your file have only 1 column, that's what you get. Evidently, by specifying `sep=","` you force `read.table(...)` to add the "extra" data as *extra rows*.

The workaround explicitly sets the number of columns by specifying column names, which could be anything, as long as `length(col.names) = 2`.

Comment: There were a couple of rows that had 3 possibilities - so I added a third column.  But thanks so much :), I never realised that was what was happening... that is, the number of columns in a data.frame is determined by the first 5 rows. Something to keep in mind in the future.